# Laravel - How to display only those Category who have products?

Tags: php, laravel

My aim is to not display the category which don't have any products as of now.

I have a drop-down list having all the category (level down to sub-category as well)

which giving me the following results.

```
Electronics
    - media
        - speaker
        - DVDs
    - Computers
Clothing
    - Mens
        - Shirt
        - Jeans
    - Women
Craft
```

But, I want to achieve following results

```
Electronics
    - media
        - speaker
    - Computers
Clothing
    - Mens
        - Shirt
```

The database tables are following

```
categories

id | name       | parent_id 
-----------------------------
1  | Electronics| null  
2  | media      | 1
3  | Clothing   | null  
4  | Craft      | null
5  | Mens       | 3
6  | Women      | 3
7  | Shirt      | 5
8  | Jeans      | 5
9  | speaker    | 2
10 | DVDs       | 2
11 | Computers  | 1


products

id | p_name                 | p_cat_id 
---------------------------------------
1  | Cotten shirt for men   | 7  
2  | New Jeans bla bal      | 7
3  | Custome gaming pc 1    | 11
4  | Custome gaming pc 2    | 11
5  | Bluetooth speaker      | 9
```

Category model

```
public function subCategory(){
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class,'p_cat_id','id')->where('status','=', 1);;
}
```

I have tried following to get category list. which gives me all the categories and sub categories

```
function getCategory() {
    return Category::where([['parent_id', '=', null], ['status', '=', 1]])->orderBy("name", "ASC")->get();
}
```

Comment: I think you can use `Has ` to get the result. ``Has will return the model's object that its relationship is not empty. ex: `Category::where()->Has('products')->get()`

Comment: @Rishni it is working but only for parent categories. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to filter out that only showing category which has least one product:

```
$categories = Category::with('products')->has('products')->get();
```

It is a simple function `->has()` will check category has any products.

```
function getCategory() {
   $categories = Category::with('products')->has('products')->get();
   return $categories;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

To make it work for sub-categories, I have fixed it for myself as following

**in Helper:**

```
function getSubcategory($catid) {
    return  Category::where([['parent_id', '=', $catid], ['status', '=', 1]])
                        ->with('products')->has('products')->get();
}
```

**In, Blade file:**

```
@if(count( getSubcategory( $category->id )) > 0)
    @include('category.subCategoryList',['subcategories' => getSubcategory( $category->id )])
@endif
```

Hope it will working for others too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is working but working for the parent categories.  The subcategories who hadn't any product yet also getting listed. I think i have to modify login for subcategories as well

Comment: @RamChander Have you tested with sub categoty?

Comment: Now Its also working for subcategory as well. for sub-categories i have fixed it myself. Thanks a lot for your response. :)

Comment: @RamChander Please update my answer with your code. so it will help others

Comment: @AmitSenjliya  sure